# How to push footer up in mobile when virtual keyboard show

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, mobile

I created React page with Parcel and I used flex column and space-between for flex items the first item is an input and the second is a button that sticks to the bottom of the page. when I open the page in mobile and press on the input box virtual keyboard shows up but my button still behind the keyboard. please help Thanks

Comment: Check that your css `z-index` for that button is higher than the keyboard.

Comment: thanks, but it does not work the virtual is mobile native keyboard